# Is it possible to add two numbers whose power is the iterator in for loop in Kotlin without using power function

Tags: android, kotlin

**Programming Language: KOTLIN**

I'm trying to make a function which adds two numbers in the following way..
**a^i+b^i** where "i" would be the iterator in for loop. So I want the i to range from 1 to 10 and print the result one by one like this... for example if I give the values as a=1 & b=2 then the result must be calculated as..
a^1+b^1= 1^1+2^1 which gives 3 so print the result.
a^2+b^2= 1^2+2^2 which gives 6 and print the result.
etc., repeating the process until "i" becomes 10.
so I tried the following code and it only prints the result of initial values.

```
fun main(){
    println(test(22,33))
}
fun test(a:Int,b:Int):Int{
    var result1=1
    var result2=1
    var result3=result1+result2
     for(i in 1..10){
         result1*=a
         result2*=b
         result3=a+b
         println(result3)
         }
     return result3
   }
```

Comment: In your text you use the symbol ^ which usually stands for _power_ and in the code you use multiplication. From the result you give (6) it probably is multiplication, because 1^2 + 2^2 would result in 5, but you should correct that if it is indeed multiplication.

Comment: Yeah! I actually mean the power , not the multiplication.

Comment: But you are aware that _1^2+2^2_ does not, quote: _... which gives 6 ..._, but it would give 5.

Comment: oh! My bad. Yup, you are right.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were only adding the parameters of your function for `result3`. This works though:

```
fun addWithIteratedPower(a: Int, b: Int) : Int {
    var resultA = 1
    var resultB = 1
    var combinedResult = 0
    for(i in 1..10){
        resultA *= a
        resultB *= b
        combinedResult = resultA + resultB
        println(combinedResult)
    }
    return combinedResult
}
```

And here's a test that validates it:

```
@Test
fun `should return final combined result`(){
    val oneAndTwoToPowerOfTenAdded = (1.0.pow(10) + 2.0.pow(10)).toInt()
    assertThat(addWithIteratedPower(1, 2)).isEqualTo(oneAndTwoToPowerOfTenAdded)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Furthermore , I wanna know if we could print the last value only one time instead of two, can we do that?. @LuckyMcBeast

Comment: @LuckMcBeast: The line _combinedResult = resultA + resultB_ could be moved out of the for loop. So it could just be _return resultA + resultB_. And the line _var combinedResult = 0_ can then be removed.

Comment: No, I mean I want each value to be printed one by one but the last one only one time instead of two times.

Comment: @Ruthwik You could, yes. You could just not return anything and call the function.

`fun main(){
    addWithIteratedPower(22,33)
}

fun addWithIteratedPower(a: Int, b: Int) {
    // code without return statement
}`

Comment: Oh! I didn't knew that. It works. Thanks again!.

Comment: @Ruthwik No problem at all :)